# 404 Error message in Django after hitting the submit button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

I got a the following error in Django after clicking the submitbutton in the browser:

> Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/send Using the URLconf defined in
> contactform.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ [name='index'] The current path, send, didn’t match any of
> these.

i have two urls in my code.
They are:

```
django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

and

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]
```

How can i solve this?
I Hope that you have a solution to this problem.

Kind Regards Win

Answer (score 0):

You are posting to an url called `send`. But you did not declare this url. What you need is something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('send/', views.send, name="send"),
]
```

Then declare a view function called `send` (as assigned in the urlpatterns). I think [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/) of the Django official tutorial may clear some concepts. Alternatively, please consider going through the whole tutorial once again.